# filter enum for Dropdown in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to create dropdown in mvc from An Enum by excluding single item.

So what ia m doing is

```
@{ 
    var imageTypesList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(ImageType));
    var filteredImageTypes = imageTypesList.Where(i => !i.Text.Equals(ImageType.LotImages.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
}
    @Html.DropDownList("TilePosition", filteredImageTypes,
        new { @class = "form-control", @Id ="ModifiedImageType" })
```

imageType is the Enum and i want to remove lotimages from the drop down.
but my code not filtering it.

what i am doing wrong? How to fix it?

```
enum ImageType{
[Display(Name = "Title Tracking Certificate")]
        TitleTrackingCertificate = 13,
        [Display(Name = "Tracking #")]
        TrackingNumber = 16,
        [Display(Name = "Lot Images")]
        LotImages = 17
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine assuming your enum is correct

Comment: but its not filtering out imagetype.lotimages from the list

Comment: Then show your `enum`

Comment: ok got the issue. i have display name, thats why string.comparison not working as expected

Comment: `ImageType` is not `imageTypes`

Comment: sorry typing mistake